# Access JSON data in Windows Forms Application

Tags: json, winforms

I have following on click event :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string usrname = textBox1.Text;
    string pass = textBox2.Text;
    Service1 ser = new Service1();
    string jay = ser.UsernamePass(usrname);

    dynamic string_json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jay);

    var password = string_json.login.Password.Value;

    if (pass == password)
    {
        h.Show();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password");
}
```

jay has Following value :

```
"{\"login\":[{\"Password\":\"admin123\"}]}"
```

string_json has following value :

```
{
    "login": [
    {
        "Password": "admin123"
    }]
}
```

At following line : var password = string_json.login.Password.Value;

It throws me following exception :

```
"'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'Password'"
```

Can anyone help me with it that how i access data?
Even it would be useful if you tell me another way to access data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, `login` is array, so try:

```
var password = string_json.login[0].Password.Value;
```

Comment: And if i want to count the entries in login then how would i do it?

Comment: Try property `Count`: [james.newtonking.com](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm)

Comment: Can u give a example same way u gave above? plz

Comment: can u state me an example plz? @Elvedin Hamzagic

Comment: Do you want to get the Count or to enumerate through JSON? It you want count type `string_json.login.Count` for array, or `string_json.login[0].Count` for object inside array.